# meaning of Selbst mit in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure

In the following sentence what does "selbst mit" means?

> Ich habe selbst mit 18 Jahren für ein Jahr als Au-pair in den USA
>   gearbeitet

Does this sentence means that I have worked at the age of 18 as AU-pair in the USA? If so, what is the significance of selbst mit in here?

Comment: *Selbst* can mean *even* or *myself*. Here, the latter is more likely, but to tell for sure the context is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"mit" belongs to "18 Jahren", not to "selbst".

> (Ich) (habe) (selbst) (mit 18 Jahren) (für ein Jahr) (als Au-pair) (in den USA) (gearbeitet)
>
> > (I) (have) (myself/personally) (when I was 18) (for one year) (as an au-pair) (in the US) (worked)
>
> > When I was 18, I (myself) have worked for one year as an au-pair in the US.

The "selbst" is redundant; it's just used for emphasis.

Comment: It is worth mentioning though that the term "selbst mit" can be meaningful in another context why that sentence sounds quite odd. Normally I'd expect some obstructing conditions to be mentioned after it like "Ich habe selbst mit vierzig Grad Fieber noch gearbeitet". You might want to mention this for the answer to be as thorough as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ich habe selbst mit 18 Jahren für ein Jahr als Au-pair in den USA gearbeitet
Translation : I have worked even with 18 years for a year as an Au-pair in the USA

Comment: Das ist zwar eine mögliche, aber eher unwahrscheinliche Deutung des *selbst* in diesem Satz.

Comment: That's not a good translation, and it's not even correct English.